# Cant't get function in controller to trigg from angularJs directive

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive, meanjs

I'm trying to run a function in my controller after the inplace edit to update my underlying data, but it doesn't trigger... can't understand why. How can I check if I'm in the right scope? I'm using Meanjs

As a test I'm trying to trigger the function testar() in my controller.

```
angular.module('customers').directive('editInPlace', [
function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        template: '<span ng-click="edit()" ng-bind="value"></span><input ng-model="value"></input>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Let's get a reference to the input element, as we'll want to reference it.
            var inputElement = angular.element(element.children()[1]);

            // This directive should have a set class so we can style it.
            element.addClass('edit-in-place');

            // Initially, we're not editing.
            scope.editing = false;

            // ng-click handler to activate edit-in-place
            scope.edit = function () {
                scope.editing = true;

                // We control display through a class on the directive itself. See the CSS.
                element.addClass('active');

                // And we must focus the element.
                // `angular.element()` provides a chainable array, like jQuery so to access a native DOM function,
                // we have to reference the first element in the array.
                inputElement[0].focus();
            };

            // When we leave the input, we're done editing.
            inputElement.prop('onblur', function () {
                scope.editing = false;
                element.removeClass('active');
                console.log("trigg");
                scope.$apply("testar()");
            });
        }
    };
}
```

]);

```
angular.module('customers').controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Customers',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Customers ) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;

    // Create new Customer
    $scope.create = function() {
        // Create new Customer object
        var customer = new Customers ({
            name: this.name,
            firstName:this.firstName
        });

    $scope.testar = function () {
        console.log("jojjemen från controller");
    }

}
```

]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your scope:

```
scope
{
  value: '=',
  controllerFunction: '='
}
```

And on your link function you call:

```
   scope.controllerFunction();
```

And then on the HTML, when you include your directive, you need to pass the controller function as an attribute:

```
<edit-in-place value="something" controller-function="testar">
```